# Updating a record with WTForms, SQLAlchemy & Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

Whenever I edit a form using WTForms, rather than it updating the record, it adds it as a new record.

I have replicated this in the Flaskr example app so it must be something I am doing wrong but I am unsure what.

I downloaded the Flaskr here: https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/tree/master/examples/flaskr

It is a simple form with two input fields - Title and Text. The form can be submitted and the entries are persisted to a sqlite database.

I tried to modify it to allow the entries to be updated.

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "entries"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(200))
    text = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)

class EntryForm(FlaskForm):
    title = TextField("Title", validators=[DataRequired()])
    text = TextAreaField("Text")
    submit = SubmitField("Share")

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)

    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate():
        entry = Entry()
        form.populate_obj(entry)
        # entry.id=1
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    else:
        flash("Your form contained errors")

    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

I added a new method to populate the form with an existing entry:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def edit_entry(id=None):
    entries = Entry.query.order_by(Entry.id.asc())
    entry = Entry.query.get(id)
    form = EntryForm(obj=entry)
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries, form=form)
```

I then added a new entry via the form and navigated to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/edit/1`, which does indeed populate the form with the entry I just created.

However, when the form is re-posted, rather than updating the existing record in the database, it inserts a new one. I thought perhaps it is because the ID is not set in the 'entry' object, but I even manually set it to 1 before saving it and it still tries to do an insert  (and fails the PK constraint) rather than an update.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but this was my approach, using Flask-SQLAlchemy. The routes are separate, but they both call on the same template to avoid repeating.

Form can take the object as an argument, and populate the form fields for "updating". The [populate_obj](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/forms.html) method then is called on the form to do just that, changing the object to reflect the new form fields. The new instance can now be added to the db.

```
@app.route("/add_item", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_item():

    form = AddItem()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        """Get instance of version from form data."""
        item = Item(field1=form.field1.data,
                    field2=form.field2.data,
                    field3=form.field3.data,
                    )
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('add_item.html', form=form)


@app.route("/edit_item/<item_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_item(item_id):

    item = db.session.query(Item).get(item_id)

    form = AddItem(obj=item)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(item)
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('add_item.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, POSTing to /add will always insert a new entry, judging by your code. The updating and inserting should be happening in separate endpoints.

SQLAlchemy provides an **object-relational mapping** between your backend and your database.  This means that, not only does SQLAlchemy see those newly constructed forms you're making as different from the one(s) that you've already inserted into the database (despite all their fields being identiacal), but any changes you make to the fields of a mapped object are reflected in that object's database entry.

You can update an object simply by querying it from its table, setting the object's fields to their updated values, and calling `db.session.commit()`. So for example:

```
    # Assuming you're using flask-sqlalchemy
    form = Entry.query.get(id)
    form.title = 'Fred Flinstone'
    form.text = 'yabba dabba doo'
    db.session.commit(form)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

But when POSTing the pre-populated form after editing it, the ID would not be passed through? So I would not be able to pull the record out of the database and update it from the form data. 

I also thought it was good practice to use form.populate_obj(entry), to load the entry object directly from the form ?

I'm trying to achieve something like this. 
https://goonan.io/flask-wtf-tricks/amp/, where New and Edit are handled in the same method. 

Thanks

Comment: If you want Naw and Edit to be handled in the same method then why does your example show them each with their own method?

Comment: Edit_entry populates EntryForm with the object whose ID was passed in. The form is always POSTed to add_entry. I am not too fussed whether they are the same method or not - I just expected that it would recognise that it is the same object (at least if it has the same primary key). It is probably because I was using plain SQLAlchemy and the examples I saw were for Flask-SQLAlchemy which handles the session differently as I understand it. I've since discovered Flask-Admin which does everything I need right out of the box but would still be interested to see if there is an elegant solution here

Answer (score 0):

a concrete example:

```
class Article(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    # price
    # stock
    category = db.Column(db.String(64))
    sub_category = db.Column(db.String(64))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())

class ArticleForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', render_kw={"placeholder": "Nombre del producto"}, validators=[
                       DataRequired(), Length(max=64)])
    category = StringField('Category', validators=[
                           DataRequired(), Length(max=64)])
    sub_category = StringField(
        'sub-category', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=64)])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', render_kw={"rows": 10, "cols": 30}, validators=[
        DataRequired()])

@app.route('/update_article/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_article(id):

    article = Article.query.get(id)

    form = ArticleForm(obj=article)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(article)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index')) 

    return render_template("add_article.html", form=form)
```

and add_article.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Edit Article
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/login.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="global-container">
    <div class="card login-form">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center"><b>Edit Article</b></h3>
            <div class="card-text">
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                    {% if messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{ messages[0] }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
                <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.name.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.name }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.category.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.category }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.category.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.sub_category.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.sub_category }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.sub_category.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.description.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.description }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.description.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.submit() }}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```